# 'git cat-file -p <sha1>': "fatal: Not a valid object name" on random objects from .git/objects

Tags: git

I want to learn more about the inner workings of git so I ran these commands:

```
cd .git/objects/62

ls
00cb2f01089db22aca24675272a16712e89747
0ee798881329430bfef6c558be7b14c1f0676f
1087f408e2f2bd782d53a1211a7418fee4f6a7
a6a71f3bd5a3af882f3f0ec4fad4c672055746
f95e69f344b52c5038d922260189475626e69a

git cat-file -p 00cb2f01089db22aca24675272a16712e89747
```

and got the following error:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name 00cb2f01089db22aca24675272a16712e89747
```

**Why did I get it?**

I tried like 10 times (for different files from different directories inside .git/objects) and got the same error.

**How can I view the actual content of the files (be it a blob, tree or commit)?**

Comment: no one seem to give a straight up answer. Just add 62 in front of the hash that you use.

Comment: ^^ A_P's comment should be the accepted answer. The folder name (62) is actually the first two characters of the hash and need to be included in the hash.

Comment: The subdirectory is named with the first 2 characters of the SHA-1, and the filename is the remaining 38 characters. [The git doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't have to cd into the `.git` object store, but you have to provide enough of the full sha1 hash for Git to uniquely identify the object.

Usually the first 6 or 7 digits are sufficient. Git matches the object IDs starting from the front, so entering any substring, such as the last several digits, will fail (or match to a different object than you intended).

```
git cat-file -p 621087f408e2f2bd782d53a1211a7418fee4f6a7
```

Git stores its objects in `.git/objects`, distributed across 256 folders to keep the size of the directory down. The first two characters of each hash are used as directory name, the remaining 38 chars are used as filename.

Comment: ok, but not cd'ing into .git object doesn't answer my questions... Why do I get the error? and how do I see the actual content of the object?

Comment: @IgorPopov: It answers your question. You tried to display an object that did not exist. Have a close look at your hash and at the hash from my answer – see the difference?

Comment: I added to the question the actual output from "ls". As you can see there is **NO** file with the name beginning with "**62**". The git cat-file fails with each of these files. If it is in the "ls" output then I guess it exists...

Comment: @IgorPopov: Have you actually tried the command I provided? And have you read the last sentence in my answer? The filenames do not correspond directly to the object hashes, because they are fanned out to 256 sub directories. The actual hash of a Git object is the directory name + filename (`6200cb2f01089db22aca24675272a16712e89747`, `620ee798881329430bfef6c558be7b14c1f0676f`, `621087f408e2f2bd782d53a1211a7418fee4f6a7`, `62a6a71f3bd5a3af882f3f0ec4fad4c672055746` and `62f95e69f344b52c5038d922260189475626e69a`)

Comment: ok, now I actually HAVE tried the command, and strangely enough: it WORKED... Now I understand... thanks for your time and answer :) --> voted and accepted!

Comment: @knittl : even with your answer, I still get the same error message. *(I created the objects with`git-unpack-objects`)*

Comment: @user2284570: using the full SHA1 hash (40 digits)?

Comment: @knittl : thanks. By the way, what is the reverse of the cat file command ? *(by reverse I mean creating an object from raw text)*

Comment: @user2284570: it's the [`hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object) command.

Comment: @knittl : unlike cat-file, it doesn’t seems to be able to handle other objects than blob. *(I want to create a 50Gb long directory name that would fit on some kb with zlib)*

Comment: @user2284570: it knows the `-t <type>` option (but the content has to be in the correct format, obviously). What on earth are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @knittl : Well, unlike contents, paths are buffered and used even before checking out. A 50Gb object would be rejected by server disk quotas. But before that, *(due to the nature of paths used by tree (not blobs))* their would be something like 110Gb ʀᴀᴍ allocation. So yes this from an exploit aside, but in order to get cash from official bounty programs. ***By the way, I’m failing to see an example command for this***.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92915/discussion-between-knittl-and-user2284570).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @knittl for a great answer.

You can get build all of the objects with this bash script.

```
cd .git/objects; 
for d in * ; do (
  cd "$d"; 
  for p in * ; do ( echo "$d$p";); done 
); done
```

Or you can get a run cat -p on everything!

```
cd .git/objects; 
for d in * ; do (
  cd "$d"; 
  for p in * ; do ( 
    echo "$d$p";
    git cat-file -p $d$p
  ); done 
); done
```

Answer (score 2):

1. SHA1's are 40 characters and `00cb2f01089db22aca24675272a16712e89747` is only **38** characters which leads me to number 2.
2. I only know this because just like you, I spent the last 20 min banging my head on the wall doing the same thing you did which was drop the 2 character prefix at the start off the SHA. Check the photo for details. [walkthrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwMc0.jpg)

Also, as a caveat, `brew install tree` if you can to get a better look at the SHA.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify a little the answer provided by @Knittl

Git store "**hashed objects**" into "**objects**" folder, but the way they store it is clever:

*folder_name + file_name = hash_code*

the command **cat-file takes that hash code** not the file_name stored into object folder, so is not necessary to be into that folder as well